# Connect to Redis through DNS with java spring-data-redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, dns, connection

I have a spring mvc webapp that uses Redis to store user session and cache manager.
Redis servers are hidden by a DNS server and I must connect to this DNS server only.
The DNS server gives me 3 redis nodes (randomically) and 2 of these nodes are down.
When DNS returns the unique active server all works fine.
When DNS returns one of unactive server I got a connection Exception.

I really becoming crazy.. I tried and tried but I didn't find a solution.
I'm using JedisConnectionFactory, someone know the solution?

Thanks
Fabrizio

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No i don't unfortunately... I only fixed it with a dns lookup to get the active node but the problem persists if whis node goes down after the connection.